# Disable use of roaming authenticators with Android WebAuthn

Tags: android, webauthn, fido

Is there a way to disable the use of roaming authenticators with WebAuthn for Android and only allow a platform authenticator to be used?

I'm using the `getSignPendingIntent` API of the [Fido2ApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fido/fido2/Fido2ApiClient#getSignPendingIntent(com.google.android.gms.fido.fido2.api.common.PublicKeyCredentialRequestOptions)) for WebAuthn, and if I try to sign in with a key that does not exist on the device's platform authenticator, it will pop up a screen asking me to setup a roaming authenticator (through USB, Bluetooth, or NFC) to continue the sign in. Instead of this option to use a roaming authenticator showing up, I want an error to be thrown if the key being used to sign in does not exist on the device's platform authenticator, or to somehow be notified that the key does not exist on the device.

Is there a way to specify this with the PublicKeyCredentialRequestOptions?

Answer (score 1):

Please, have a look at theAuthenticator Attachement enumeration that is passed in the options during the registration ceremony : https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#enum-attachment

It allows you to prevent the registration of roaming authenticators.

Answer (score 0):

This can be specified by setting the [Transport](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fido/common/Transport) option to `Transport.INTERNAL` in the [PublicKeyCredentialDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fido/fido2/api/common/PublicKeyCredentialDescriptor) setting.